# A UART driver that emulates getchar()

Tags: c, embedded, driver, uart, getchar

I have a driver for a UART that reads a string of data for the serial console until the user enter 'l'. However, I just want to read a single char. It is for a menu where the user enters 1-9 or a-z. I'm trying to create an equivalent of the standard C `getchar()`. How could I generally do this?

This is the register map for the UART.

[image]

```
void getstring(char *str) {

    volatile uint32_t *uart = (volatile uint32_t*) UART;
    char c = 0;

    do {
        while ((uart[2] & (1<<7)) == 0);
        c = uart[0];
        *str++ = c;
    }
    while (c!='l');
}
```

Comment: We are no coding/tutoring service. What is your **specific** problem? Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Just refactor this function, move the code inside the loop into a getchar() function.  The `uart` declaration is buggy, it needs to be `uint16_t` to match the register size.

Comment: This `getstring()` implementation is unsafe and ill advised.  It has no limit on the number of characters written to `str`, does not terminate the string, and includes the `l` character used to terminate entry.

Comment: The standard library `getchar()` operates at a higher level and is normally line buffered- that is probably not the behaviour you want, and if it is, you are better off re-targeting your compiler's standard library to use this UART for `stdin`/`stdout`

Comment: "Driver" is somewhat overstating the function of that code.  It is simply reading the UART registers directly.

Comment: @HansPassant : The registers may still be 32-bit aligned - presumably the case if this code works at all.

Answer (score 0):

The loop retrieves one character at a time in a loop.  If you want just a single character then simply omit outer the loop.

```
char getch() 
{
    volatile uint32_t *uart = (volatile uint32_t*) UART;
    while ((uart[2] & (1<<7)) == 0);
    return uart[0];
}
```

It then makes sense to re-write `getstring()` using this function (more maintainable).